# Slow down in Debug.Log cause in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I deployed

```
Debug.Log(“Something cools”);
```

Not in `Update` or `StartCoroutine`,`Invoke`

1. It delay some seconds to show in Console after code call it.
2. If I start, and stop immediately Play mode, debug is shown.

Not only debug, code in block contains Debug seem not working.

Which problem I have and how to solve it ?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I check that if I shutdown my Laptop to make it not hot, it show Debug.Log immediatly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Much like `console.WriteLine()`, `Debug.Log()` can slow down performance. Although, unless you are calling it several times in a single Update pass, it shouldn't be very noticeable.

If you would like to learn more about how it slows down performance, and ways to stop this happening, then check out this great [game dev article here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAMQw7AJahcKEwj4pLTx2pT-AhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgamedevbeginner.com%2Fhow-to-use-debug-log-in-unity-without-affecting-performance%2F&psig=AOvVaw36C3sVFdmORpe3o7KHvEao&ust=1680851748684938). It shows you the best methods for using Debug.Log to ensure you don't slow down your computer.

Hope this helps. Happy coding!